# Scala Actors: if react never returns, why does it need to be in a loop{}, and why doesn't while(true) work?

Tags: scala, actor

Just getting started on Scala Actors. The [Scala website](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/242) says:

> Thread-blocking operations can be avoided by using `react` to wait for
>   new messages (the event-based pendant of `receive`). However, there is a
>   (usually small) price to pay: `react` never returns.
>
> ...
>
> Note that using `react` inside a `while` loop does not work! However,
>   since loops are common there is special library support for it in form
>   of a `loop` function. It can be used like this:

```
loop {
  react {
    case A => ...
    case B => ...
  }
}
```

I'm now confused - there seems to be a contradiction:

a) If `react` never returns, then what's the point of putting it in a loop?

b) Since `loop` repeatedly executes a block, how is it any different to `while(true)` - why doesn't `while` work, and in what way does it "not work"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both functions, `loop` and `react` are not pure. `loop` takes a call by name parameter and `react` a PartialFunction, both set variables on the raw actor. This is because an actor does not have a thread attached all the time. It will become active only when there is a message in it's messagebox. This is why a `while(true)` will lead to 100% cpu usage and the actor not responding.

Comment: So the missing part of the Scala website explanation is that `react` doesn't return _normally_ but does still terminate (maybe via an Exception?) and is thus called repeatedly?

Comment: I don't think it is a 'missing part'. It's an implementation detail and irrelevant for the developer. The relevant information is that while(true) doesn't work. If you are interested in the details you can however look at the sources, I often do that to understand things better.

Comment: It's maybe irrelevant if you just follow the recipe, but it was a major stumbling block in the explanation, for me - whether something returns or not isn't an implementation detail (if you are trying to loop/repeat it) - it's absolutely fundamental! I took a quick look at the sources before asking the question but I will follow your advice to dig a bit deeper...

Answer (score 1):

I found an explanation that answers part *a)* of my question, in [one of Haller and Odersky's papers on Actors](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/%7Eodersky/papers/jmlc06.pdf) (my emphasis below):

> The central idea is as follows: An actor that waits in a receive
> statement is not represented by a blocked thread but by a closure that
> captures the rest of the actor's computation. The closure is executed
> once a message is sent to the actor that matches one of the message
> patterns specied in the receive. The execution of the closure is
> \piggy-backed" on the thread of the sender.
>
> If the receiving closure
> terminates, control is returned to the sender as if a procedure
> returns. If the receiving closure blocks in a second receive, control
> is returned to the sender **by throwing a special exception** that unwinds
> the receiver's call stack.
>
> A necessary condition for the scheme to
> work is that receivers never return **normally** to their enclosing actor.
> In other words, no code in an actor can depend on the termination or
> the result of a receive block...

Comment: I wanted to see if I could get a way to contact you regarding a development / consulting project that might fit your skills. What would be a good way to reach out?

Comment: My profile has contact email - but I'm fully occupied at present, sorry.