# What does it mean to say that a method (such as 'react)' does not return?

Tags: scala, actor

In Scala actors, we always learn that "[react does not return](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors.html)". What exactly does this mean? What is the difference between a method that "does not return" and one that returns `Unit`.

I was under the impression that every method must eventually finish (and may or may not return anything). So what happens when `react` finishes?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704696/scala-actors-if-react-never-returns-why-does-it-need-to-be-in-a-loop-and-wh

Answer (score 2):

```
def react(...): Nothing = ...
```

You can't get an instance of `Nothing`. It means `react` will newer finishes correctly.

It will run forever or will throw an exception eventually.

```
react(...)
println("You'll never get here!")
```

In case of `Actor#react` it just [throws](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/actors/scala/actors/Reactor.scala#L204) an exception.

Method `loop` catches this exception. For detailed explanation see [Actors that Unify Threads and Events](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~phaller/doc/haller07coord.pdf), Philipp Haller and Martin Odersky, Proc. COORDINATION 2007. You don't need this details to work with actors, you should just know that all the code after `react` is unreachable:

```
loop {
  <code before react>
  react {...}
  <unreachable code>
}
```